# Is there a better console for PHP than running in interactive mode

Tags: php, console, read-eval-print-loop

Is there something like [ipython](/questions/tagged/ipython) for PHP? Syntax highlighting and not having the console exit to shell on the first exception would be nice to haves. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Interactive Shell will be improved in PHP 5.4.

See http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/133-Now-in-trunk-Improved-interactive-shell.html

> Improved CLI Interactive readline shell (Johannes)
>
> - Added cli.pager ini setting to set a pager for output.
> - Added cli.prompt ini settingto configure the shell prompt.
> - Added shortcut #inisetting=value to change ini settings at run-time.
> - Don't terminate shell on fatal errors.

An alternative would be http://phpsh.org/

> phpsh is an interactive shell for php that features readline history, tab completion, quick access to documentation. It was developed at Facebook and ironically, is written mostly in python. It is open source and released under a modified BSD license.

Comment: One of the key changes is missing in that list: It now (= PHP 5.4) also support cases where the readline module is compiled shared, so there's a good chance it will work with distributor packages. I should update the blog post ... thought it was in there but the blog post is too old, it seems

Comment: and just for future reference: What was called PHP.next / PHP 5.3.99 back then is now called PHP 5.4

Comment: I would add here, since this is the "correct" answer, that [PsySH](http://psysh.org) have great features, although they haven't implemented tab-completion yet.
PHPSH depends on python, and [PHP-Shell](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/php-shell/) have great tab-completion.

Answer (score 8):

Justin just gave a talk on the interactive shell Psysh at OSCON which appears to be an improved version of phpsh.

https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh

Answer (score 1):

Never tried, but http://david.acz.org/phpa/ sounded promising. The page also lists two alternatives which might be worth to investigate. There were also some musings that the builtin `php -a` was refurbished in php-trunk/5.4. So maybe try the SVN version (at least it supports non-ASCII input).